# Unable to make VM use public IP with macvtap/KVM/libvirt

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, libvirt

I am running dedicated server with few KVM VMs on it. I had success in the past getting separate public IPv4 address attached to one VM using macvtap driver and it works just like totally independent server just fine.

I am copying everything I am doing for the second public IPv4 I received from hosting service provider, but this time I can not access internet from second VM using macvtap.

Here is relevant host's `ip link show` for newly created macvtap interface when VM is launched by libvirt:

```
40: macvtap2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
link/ether 52:54:00:35:02:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And here is guest's `ifconfig` output:

```
ens10     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:35:02:38  
      inet addr:[PUBLIC IP]  Bcast:[BROADCAST IP PROVIDED BY HOSTER]  Mask:255.255.255.224
      inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe35:238/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1230 (1.2 KB)
```

Here is relevant section from `virsh edit machine`:

```
    <interface type='direct'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:35:02:38'/>
      <source dev='eth0' mode='vepa'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

When I am running `tcpdump -vv host [PUBLIC VM IP]` I can see incoming packets, but never response.

I see nothing in `tcpdump -vv -i ens10` VMs output at all.

Similar setup seems to work with another VM and I fail to find what difference between two can cause second VM working the same. Anything I can do to debug it further?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was matter of requesting separate MAC address for my virtual machine from Hetzner (my hoster) and not use randomly generated by libvirt one. Once I requested and updated config everything else just started working.

Some details: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Virtualisierung/en